# How to execute multiple coroutines concurrently and do something when some coroutines finishes?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine

### Context

I have three recipe classes which shares a common ingredient.

```py
class BrewedNoodle:
    ingredients: list[Coroutine] = [Noodle]

    async def cook(noodle: Noodle):
        pass

class PorkNoodle:
    ingredients: list[Coroutine] = [Noodle, Pork]

    async def cook(noodle: Noodle, pork: Pork):
        pass


class BeefNoodle:
    ingredients: list[Coroutine] = [Noodle, Beef]

    async def cook(noodle: Noodle, beef: Beef):
        pass
```

please consider each indredient as an API (needs network call)

### What I want to do

I want to perform `asyncio.gather()` to fetch(prepare) each ingredients concurrently.
and as soon as all necessary ingredients are prepared for a specific recipe, I want to cook it immediately, not waiting for other ingredients.

For example:

1. as soon as Noodle is prepared, I cook BrewedNoodle.
2. And Pork is prepared, (since Noodle and Pork is ready) then I cook PorkNoodle.
3. And after the beef is prepared I cook BeefNoodle.

### What I actually did

but I'm awaiting `asyncio.gather()`, I'm destined to wait until all ingredients are ready. (I can not pre-cook BrewedNoodle even if Noodle is prepared)

```py
# prepare ingredients
noodle, pork, beef = await asyncio.gather(Noodle(), Pork(), Beef())


# cook
BrewedNoodle().cook(noodle)
PorkNoodle().cook(noodle, pork)
BeefNoodle().cook(noodle, beef)
```

### Question

How can I cook a Recipe when necessary ingredients are ready without waiting for other ingredients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your example correctly, there needs to be some kind of explicit mapping from ingredients to the dishes that can be created from them. The special case of `Noodle` being required for the other dishes also needs to be addressed separately. The core of the algorithm is [`asyncio.as_completed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed):

```py
dishes = {
    Noodle: BrewedNoodle,
    Pork: PorkNoodle,
    Beef: BeefNoodle,
}
ingredients = [Noodle(), Pork(), Beef()]
noodle = None
for coro in asyncio.as_completed(ingredients):
    ingredient = await coro
    dish = dishes[type(ingredient)]
    if isinstance(ingredient, Noodle):
        dish.cook(ingredient)
        noodle = ingredient
    else:
        # Pork or Beef, assuming noodle has already finished
        dish.cook(noodle, ingredient)
```